# How to update a data element to contain only unique values (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

I have values in a database table

| id | diagnosis |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Z590HeartFailureZ590HeartFailureZ610ChronicAbuse |
| 2 | Z590HeartFailureZ590HeartFailure |

I need to run an update so it looks like this (with no repeat values)

| id | diagnosis |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Z590HeartFailureZ610ChronicAbuse |
| 2 | Z590HeartFailure |

How can I remove duplicates in a data element in postgresql?

Comment: By unique values I am referring to the diagnosis code (for example, 'Z590HeartFailure' is a unique value, and so is 'Z610ChronicAbuse')

Comment: How long is one code, do you have a regex to identify a code? Are they always sorted or can they be in random order like `Code1Code2Code1`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expressions in order to analyse the `diagnosis` data and remove the duplicates. We assume that a `diagnosis` data is made of one upper case alphabetical character, then one or more numeric characters, then a set of one upper case alphabetical character followed by one or more lower case alphaberical characters.

You can try the following query :

```
SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT b.data[1], '')
  FROM (VALUES ('Z590HeartFailureZ590HeartFailureZ610ChronicAbuse'), ('Z590HeartFailureZ590HeartFailure')) AS a(data)
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL regexp_matches(a.data, '([A-Z]\d+([A-Z][a-z]+)+)', 'g') AS b(data)
 GROUP BY a.data
```

result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6530cd01caee3ca57e3796f73d178421).